# Mongoose Conditional Populating

Tags: mongoose, populate, mongoose-populate

I have this code where I want to get the pending invoices, and I only want to get the client and the amount fields.

```
const query = {status:"pending"};
const fields = "amount client";

const invoices = await Invoice.find(query,fields)
      .populate({model: 'User',path: 'currentResponsible'});
      .populate({model: 'User',path: 'responsible1'});
      .populate({model: 'User',path: 'responsible2'});
      .populate({model: 'Client', path: 'client'});
```

In this case mongoose gives me the pending invoices but populates the fields 'currentResponsible', 'responsible1','responsible2' with information that I don't need and that I haven't requested in the 'fields' constant.

**I would want a 'Conditional Populate' that only populates the object if I require that field in the 'fields' constant.**

The main objective is to create a modular GET API endpoint that allows me to send the 'query' and the 'fields' constants from the front-end in order to get only the information that I need from different parts of the application.

I tried the following according to this [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63714713/mongoose-conditional-populate-with-findbyid) and [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate_an_existing_mongoose_document), but the performance is ultra slow (it took 1 min to retrieve and populate 1.300 documents, it's not a viable solution.)

```
const query = {status:"pending"};
const fields = "amount client";

const invoices = await Invoice.find(query,fields)

const populatedInvoices = []
for (const invoice of invoices) {
  if(fields.includes("client")){
    await invoice.populate({model: 'Client', path: 'client'}).execPopulate();
  }
  if(fields.includes("currentResponsible")){
    await invoice.populate({model: 'User', path: 'currentResponsible'}).execPopulate();
  }
  if(fields.includes("responsible1")){
    await invoice.populate({model: 'User', path: 'responsible1'}).execPopulate();
  }
  if(fields.includes("responsible2")){
    await invoice.populate({model: 'User', path: 'responsible2'}).execPopulate();
  }
  populatedInvoices.push(invoice)
}
```

The solution commented in the post and documentation mentioned before works if the method is 'findOne()' (for just one document) but in my case I would want it to work for 'find()' (for multiple documents)

Thank you in advance for your help! :D

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution thanks to Chat GPT :D
Since not all fields of the invoice model needs to be populated, I created a constant with all the fields that needs to be populated, this way if I ask for those invoices fields I will get them

```js
const query = {status:"Pending",amount:{$gt:0}}
const fields = "client amount currentResponsible invoice status"
const INVOICE_FIELDS_TO_POPULATE = ['currentResponsible','responsible1', 'responsible2', 'client']
const invoices = await Invoice.find(query,fields).populate(fields.split(' ').filter(field=>INVOICE_FIELDS_TO_POPULATE.includes(field)).map((field) => ({ path: field })))
```

This way I can **query invoices, get only the information I need, and fill the fields that needs to be populated**. And this pattern could be applied to any model or resource from an API.